# Toast message from background only displays while in main activity; not other activities

Tags: android, android-toast

This problem is a little different from most 'display toast' issues. I am not asking to display Toast messages in other activities **but to see Toast messages sent by a background service while in another activity *besides* the main activity**. I DO see the Toast messages in the main activity!

I have an application that has a background service. When certain events happen in this background service a Toast message is displayed. The background service receives data from external BT and BLE devices and sends messages out over wifi. The toast messages show certain important events in those processes. The `MainActivity` and the background service use the application context from `getApplicationContext()` for the display of this toast message.

However, these messages do not display if I move to another `Activity`. For example, to configure some parameters. I am not trying to display toast messages from other activities; that I can do. But how can I get the toast messages from the background service to also display while I am in another `Activity` besides the `MainActivity`? I think I will need to do something like 'run the activity on the application context' though I have no idea how to do it (or even if it is possible).

Comment: please provide your code

Answer (score 1):

Use `BroadcastReceiver` for this purpose. In each of your `Activity` you need to declare a `BroadcastReceiver` like this.

```
private class ShowToastBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String message = intent.getStringExtra("Message");
        Toast.makeText(OtherActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

You need to register the `BroadcastReceiver` each time in your `onResume` and unregister it back in `onPause` function of your activities.

```
// This is in your Activity

private ShowToastBroadcastReceiver showToastBroadcastReceiver;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    showToastBroadcastReceiver = new ShowToastBroadcastReceiver();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(showToastBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("SHOW_TOAST"));
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(showToastBroadcastReceiver);
}
```

Now you need to send the broadcast from your `Service` to get the toast to be shown in your `Activity`.

```
// This is in your Service

Intent intent = new Intent("SHOW_TOAST");
intent.putExtra("Message", "This toast needs to be shown");
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: Reaz, I am not having a problem sending Toast messages from my service. I see them fine BUT ONLY WHILE IN MY MAIN ACTIVITY (I use a Broadcast Receiver in one case and a Handler in another). That is not the problem. It's when I move to another activity, say to look at debug output, that I no longer see these messages though the service continues to work and the Toast messages continue to be sent. I know that is the case because it continues to work with external devices.

Comment: Did you try sending broadcast? Did you register the broadcast in every other activity?

Comment: You have found the answer for me because I did something real stupid. Not in registering the Broadcast receiver but in its unregistration. I had the latter at too high of a level. I needed to put it in onDestroy and not onStop(). What an idiot I was!

Comment: Glad to know that helped. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to display a `Toast` from any context, including a `Service`. The [Toast Notifications](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html) developer guide has sample code that shows how:

```
Context context = getApplicationContext();
CharSequence text = "Hello toast!";
int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
toast.show();
```

In other words, you don't need an `Activity` at all. You can display the `Toast` directly from the `Service`. If you're worried about doing it from a separate thread, create a `Handler` in the main thread of the `Service` and post a `Runnable` or message to that handler to display the `Toast`.

One other possibility is that you are using a bound service and it is going away when you switch away from the main activity. Make sure the service itself is still running.

Oh, and also make sure that the 'Show notifications' setting for your app hasn't been unchecked.

Comment: Thanks Ted but that is not the problem. I am displaying Toast messages from a background service which never goes away using a Broadcast Receiver and in another case a Handler. I know the service is not going away because it successfully exchanges data with an external device. But I only see these Toast messages while in my main Activity. If I should move from my main activity to another activity, for example to configure some parameters or look at some debug output, I no longer see these Toast messages though they are being sent.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Reaz I found a stupid error I had made. I was unregistering the BroadcastReceiver handling the Toasts at onStop() instead of onDestroy(). Moving the unregistration to onDestroy() and registration and filters to onCreate() solved the problem.